# Deployement using Cruise Control .Net

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

Currently i am using Cruise Control .Net.
I want to automate this deployment process.
now i am doing following below step by msbuild script.

```
GetSource=Get the source code from svn.  
Before Build=build the web project.  
Publish=publish the web project.  
zip=zip the publish folder.
```

here up to  everything is fine but how to deploy this zip folder in different server.i guess, i should use ftp system.but i haven't work on it.please suggest how to go ahead with this scenario would be fine if you provide any sample demo project or code

Comment: You need to think of CC.NET as a "big fancy msbuild.exe executer".  Write all of your logic in msbuild.  Use the cc.net source control task to bring down your source control (perhaps even a single .msbuild file (aka, .proj file)............and then have cc.net call "msbuild.exe MyBuildDef.proj".

Answer (score 0):

To upload a folder / zip to a server, CC.NET have a buildin task named `ftp`

```
 <ftp>
   <serverName>ftp.isp.com</serverName>
   <userName>john</userName>
   <password>doe</password>
   <action>UploadFolder</action>
   <ftpFolderName>site/config</ftpFolderName>
   <localFolderName>d:\website\config</localFolderName>
   <recursiveCopy>true</recursiveCopy>
 </ftp>
```

Reference:
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Ftp_task_-_Publisher

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the logic (as much as you can, which is usually 99%).......inside "msbuild land".

This way, if you ever move away from CC.NET (TFS for example), you minimize the code you have to translate.

Here is the  task.

https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Source/MSBuild.Community.Tasks/Ftp/FtpUploadDirectoryContent.cs

Example:

```
/// <Target Name="DeployWebsite">
/// <FtpUploadDirectoryContent
/// ServerHost="ftp.myserver.com"
/// Port="42"
/// Username="user"
/// Password="p@ssw0rd"
/// LocalDirectory="c:\build\mywebsite"
/// RemoteDirectory="root\www\mywebsite"
/// Recursive="true"
/// />
```